# How to Create a curved scrollbar in android wear 2.0?

Tags: android, wear-os

[image: android wear 2.0]

I am using WearableRecyclerView to create a curved layout,but the default scrollbar is still vertical.Is there a way to create a curved scrollbar like android wear 2.0 launcher?

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the scrollbars are circular for any scrollable View that takes up the whole screen. It's a framework feature for Wear 2.0.

If the scrollbars are still vertical, make sure your View really does fill up the whole screen - set it to match_parent and as a top level root View.

Comment: This worked for me, view doesnt need to be root view but needs to fill entire view port (i had margin top set which breaks the scroll). Ridiculous that this isnt documented anywhere

Comment: This is f**king ridiculous. Adding margin on only the LEFT or RIGHT (not even margin top) prevents a curved scrollbar. Zero documentation on this. As of Nov 2023 they are also requiring scrollbars in your WearOS app, otherwise they won't allow you to update your app.

Comment: If I hadn't seen your answer @ScruffyFox, I honestly would have given up on updating my WearOS app.

Answer (score 1):

use boxinsetlayout

//
android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout

app:layout_box="left|bottom|right"

...Your list View and other contents

android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout>

and if you are using wearableRecyclerView
do `CircularChildLayoutManager mChildLayoutManager = new CircularChildLayoutManager(mContext);`
and set this as layout manager for your recycler view.

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mChildLayoutManager);
```

This may solve for you.

Comment: I already  used BoxInsetLayout , and adding app:layout_box="left|bottom|right" still not working.

Comment: consider properly formatting your answer, with code block or backticks for better readability

Comment: I am new to stack ... so never mind... i will improve accordingly... thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The API was renamed to `CurvedChildLayoutManager`

So use

```
val layoutManager = CurvedChildLayoutManager(this)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

PS: as for topic question, you dont need `app:layout_box` just use `android:scrollbars="vertical"` on your `WearableRecyclerView`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/CurvedChildLayoutManager.html

Comment: I cannot resolve CurvedChildLayoutManager class, do you know why? my dependency is 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.1'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
}

Comment: @fangjack try 2.0.1

Comment: I change to 2.0.1,the CurvedChildLayoutManager   was imported.But using CurvedChildLayoutManager  doesn't work as i expected,the scrollbar is still vertical,and not curved.

Comment: same for me, the scrollbar is still vertical!

Comment: Unfortunately this answer is deprecated